# Why is my JavaScript database table is empty?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sql, database

I want to insert a database with SQL in my website, but the code doesn't work.

What I mean is, there is a problem in the table of the database - after execution, it's showing as empty, I need help to solve this problem.

Also, I would like to know, is it correct to make the value name in HTML code like it's "prenom" in that example `document.f.prenom.value`, or should I make an `id` instead?

This is the code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', inscrire);

function inscrire() {
  var nom = document.f.nom.value;
  var prenom = document.f.prenom.value;
  var adresse = document.f.adresse.value;
  var email = document.f.email.value;
  var telephone = document.f.tel.value;
  var db = openDatabase('fashion', '1.0', 'amal DB', 200000);
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
      mytable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nom TEXT, prenom TEXT, adresse TEXT, email TEXT, telephone TEXT, choix TEXT, message TEXT)
      '); 
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO members  (nom, prenom, adresse, email, telephone, choix, message) VALUES( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )
        ',[nom,prenom,adresse,email,telephone,choix,message]);
      });
  });
}
```

This is my html code:

```
<body>
  <form name="f" onsubmit="inscrire()">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Nom:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input required="required" type="TEXT" name="nom" /> <br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Prénom:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input required="required" type="TEXT" name="prenom" /> <br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Adresse:
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea required="required" type="TEXT" rows="3" cols="22" name="adresse"> </textarea><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Mail:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input required="required" type="email" name="email" /> <br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Téléphone:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input required="required" type="tel" minlength="8" maxlength="8" name="tel" /> <br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Choix:
        </td>
        <td>
          <input required="required" type="TEXT" name="choix" /> <br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Message:
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea required="required" type="TEXT" rows="8" cols="22" name="message"> </textarea><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" id="btn" />
    <input type="reset" value="Annuler" id="btn" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You really want to use javascript to edit database? After all, the user can interfere in the JS code and, for example, destroy the database.

Comment: yes, actually i have a phomework that we are intrested only about javascript. @KrzysztofAN

Comment: OK I understand. So try to use: `window.openDatabase`, instead only: `openDatabase`.